# Plotting unique values collapsed by years in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data set of the form

```
x<- c("London","Newyork","Miami","London","London","London")
y<- c(2008,2009,2008,2010,2009,2008)
df<- data.frame(x,y)
plot(length(unique(df$x)),y)
```

Now I want to plot unique values of x(length) and y based on years. I am expecting graph like 2008- 2; 2009-2; 2010-1. I need to collapse based on unique values of the city counts. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please include a desired plot? it is not clear to me your goal.

Comment: Do you want `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(n=n_distinct(x))`

Comment: yep i am trying to plot years v/s unique cities present in the data. For example the first point is x value =2008 and y= 2 (as it includes London, Miami, London- I am interested in unique values and hence it is 2). Is it clear now?

Comment: The fact that you want to plot this seems to have nothing to do with the question really being asked.

Comment: yep @akrun! precisely that's what i was looking for! Awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n_distinct` is a convenient function in `dplyr` to find the count of `unique` elements.  Here, we group by 'y' column and get the `n_distinct` of 'y'.  This can be used for plotting with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>% 
     group_by(y) %>% 
     summarise(n=n_distinct(x)) %>%
     ggplot(., aes(x=y, y=n)) +
            geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tapply` to count the distinct values per year and `barplot` for plotting.

```
barplot(with(df, tapply(x, y, function(v) length(unique(v)))))
```

Comment: Or `barplot(colSums(table(df)>0))`